# Cleaning Data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean the data I have this first column that I extracted the city code but there is a problem the state code I could not extracted because there is no way to extract it other than manually as far as I know. I tried using chatgpt but I couldn't reach to a solution. I used the split function to split using spaces but there are some cities that doesn't have two spaces so the state code goes to the city2 column

what could be best technical solution for this

[image]

I did try the splitting the function

Comment: so write an if() with right() to get the last 3 characters then test if the first one is a space.

Comment: Do you have lists of city codes and state codes you can check against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Split Delimited Data

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:A21,lmDelimiter,"-",StateChars,2,Comma,",",
    d,SUBSTITUTE(data,Comma,""),
    l,IFERROR(TRIM(TEXTBEFORE(d,lmDelimiter,,1,,"")),""),
    rt,TRIM(TEXTAFTER(d,lmDelimiter,,1,,TRIM(d))),
    rc,RIGHT(rt,StateChars),e,EXACT(rc,UPPER(rc)),
    m,IFERROR(IF(e,TRIM(LEFT(rt,LEN(rt)-2)),rt),""),
    r,IFERROR(IF(e,rc,""),""),
    dr,HSTACK(l,m,r),
dr)
```

- It is based on user11222393's idea *"all state codes are 2 upper letters"*.
- Replace the last `dr` with any of the other variables to see what they return.

Comment: Could you explain please. you are my chatgpt now

Answer (score -1):

So like this:

[image]

As text, to save you the effort of typing:

```
IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A3,3),1)=" ",RIGHT(A3,2),"")
```

a quick explanation:

Right(A3,3) gets the last 3 characters, then left() takes the first character of those 3. The logical test is to see if that first character is a space ie compared to a space. If() then returns the last 2 characters if true and blank if false.

As for the suggestion of checking for 2 uppercase characters, that is left as an exercise.

Comment: I don't know if there are many cities with 2 letter 2nd word, but at least "Santa Fe" would give false positive

Comment: @user11222393 I would much rather  check manually for those few than do all the data manually :)

Comment: That is for sure much faster :)

Comment: could please explain

Comment: @SolarMike time will show. Also I would suggest checking if those 2 letters are uppercase as in given data example all state codes are 2 upper letters while cities has only first upper.